# How to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n^{2}+1)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n^{2}+1)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ . I am wondering if I can use the ratio test to prove this? When I use the ratio test I get the following:

$\frac{((n+1)^{2}+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{(n^{2}+1)^\frac{1}{n}}$

But this is painfully difficult to handle, am I doing the right things?

Or should I do the following:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then let us consider the sequence, ${\frac{n^{2}+1}{(1+\epsilon)^{n}}}$. Then we have by the ratio test that:

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{(n^{2}+2)}{(1+\epsilon)^{n+1}}\frac{(1+\epsilon)^{n}}{n^{2}+1} = \frac{n^{2}+2}{n^{2}+1}\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$. And since the term on the left goes to 1, as n goes to infinity, we would have that this ratio test would just equal $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}$, which is less than 1, and hence this sequence converges to 0.

So from this knowledge we can say that ${\frac{n^{2}+1}{(1+\epsilon)^{n}}} < 1$, and so, ${{n^{2}+1} < {(1+\epsilon)^{n}}}$. And so if we raise LHS and RHS to $\frac{1}{n}$ we have proved it?

Comment: Your proof looks essentially right. You can make it rigorous by saying there is some $n>N$ such that $| \frac{n^2+1}{{(1+\epsilon)}^n}-0|<1$ which is using the the epsilon delta definition of limit with an epsilon of 1. So when n is within this range, definitely ${\frac{n^2+1}{(1+\epsilon)^{n}}} < 1$. So then you have $1 < {{n^{2}+1} < {(1+\epsilon)^{n}}}$. Take the nth root. Then use squeeze theorem for the limit as n approaches infinity. Your right term is now $1+\epsilon$. Then take the limit as your epsilon goes to zero. The left and middle term don't change. The right limit goes to 1.

Comment: You should have $(n+1)^2+1 = n^2+2n+2$ not $n^2+2$. But that doesn't change the limit, so the rest is still fine.

Comment: But how would I still show that $\frac{n^{2}+2n+2}{n^{2}+1}$ will tend to 1 without using calculus?

Comment: Just divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$. You get $\frac{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know for a seuence $\{x_n\}_n^\infty$ of positive reals, if $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L \in [0,\infty]$ then $\lim {x_{n}}^{\frac1 n}=L$.

So, $$\lim \frac{(n+1)^2+1}{n^2+1}=\lim \frac{(1+\frac1 n)^2+\frac 1 {n^2}}{1+\frac1 {n^2}}=1\\ \implies \lim (n^2+1)^{\frac 1 n}=1$$

Comment: No , obviously. I am taking $n \to \infty$, but e=$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{\frac1 x}$

Answer (score 5):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2+1)^\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(n^2)}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{2\ln n}{n}}=e^0=1
$$

Comment: I am not supposed to be using the e definition.

Comment: So no logarithms allowed?

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$n^{2/n} \leqslant (n^2+1)^{1/n} \leqslant (2n^2)^{1/n} = 2^{1/n} n^{2/n}$$

By the squeeze  theorem it follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^2+1)^{1/n}  = 1$, since $2^{1/n} \to 1$ and $n^{2/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

That $2^{1/n} \to 1$ is well-known and easy to prove. To show that $n^{2/n}\to 1$, we have $n^{2/n} \geqslant 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for $n > 2$ using the binomial theorem we have

$$n^2 = (1+ (n^{2/n}-1))^n> \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}(n^{2/n} -1)^3$$

Thus, for all $n > 2$,

$$0 < n^{2/n}- 1 < \sqrt[3]{\frac{6n}{(n-1)(n-2)}} \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow 0$$